# Using templates as keys in a std::map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I am wondering whether it is possible to use a template as a key for a map.  For instance:

```
std::map< <T> , Node> nodes;
```

In essence, what I want to do is be able to have a bunch of nodes that contain arbitrary types data, and are keyed by that data.  I think I could do it by converting said data to binary and keying by that, but that is messy and I want to avoid it.

To clarify, I want to be able to use a variable of any type as the key.  For example if I have 2 nodes, one that contains an int as its data, and another that contains a Foo as its data, I want to be able to put those in the same map using their data as the key.  Maybe a map is not what I want, I am not sure...

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to choose a specific type in order to instantiate that class. However, you could take a look at Boost Any: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: Runtime or compile-time? If compile-time, aren't you looking for template<typename T> constexpr ...? If runtime, typeid as below.

Comment: While not pretty for a large number of possible types, [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) is an option.

Comment: Also consider whether you actually need a `std::map` or whether a `std::unordered_map` will suffice, this will avoid having to define the less than comparison for different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't disabled RTTI explicitly, refer to nogard's answer. Standard type id is garanteed to be unique for a whole program across DLL. This is not true for the address of a function.

What I usually do is this:

```
template<typename T>
void type_id(){}

using type_id_t = void(*)();
```

Then, I use it like this:

```
std::map<type_id_t, Node> nodes;

nodes[type_id<AType>] = Node{...};
nodes[type_id<BType>] = Node{...};
```

Of course, this can be enhanced with variable template from C++14.

---

Sorry, I just re-read the question and I understand it better.

What you want is [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any), but it's C++17 only. You can use `boost::any` instead.

It will look like this:

```
std::map<std::any, Node> nodes;

nodes.emplace("string as key", Node{});
nodes.emplace(23, Node{});
```

It should work as long as the map can somehow order instances of `std::any`. If not, you can use hash map instead:

```
std::unordered_map<std::any, Node> nodes;
```

Then it will work as long as the map can hash an any.

Comment: @vtleavs a type which is able to hold value of any type. [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: I made a link to the standard library documentation. I can paste it again here if you want: [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)

Comment: @RichardHodges That's why I mentionned the unodered_map. Hashing `any`s can be possible.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot how will you test for equality? I have posted an answer which will work for all map and set types.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this purpose it's much easier to use `std::type_info` for the types:

```
std::map<std::type_info, std::string> m;
m[typeid(int)] = "integer";
```

But this really depends on what you want to achieve, it's still unclear to me. Hope that helps

Comment: If it is unclear what the question is how you can answer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It does compile actually with my gcc 5, maybe you are using older compiler? Also documentation states explicitly to use std::type_info, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: Does type_index use the type as a key, or does it use keys of any type?  I am looking to be able to use data of any type as a key, not the type itself.

Answer (score 1):

At least if I understand what you want, the short answer is no.

The keys in a map must be ordered--that is, you must define for any pair of keys A and B, you must define an ordered relationship where either A is less than B, or B is less than A, or the two keys are equivalent.

Given two keys of entirely arbitrary types there's not going to be a defined way of comparing them. Therefore, you can't use them as keys in for a map.

To get something sort of close, you'll need to define some specific set of types  you want to support. Then you can define something that's (roughly) a union of all the types you want to support. That alone won't be enough though--you'll also have to define ordering. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might have (for example) an ID in every one of those objects, and order them by ID. Alternatively, you might define an ordering between objects, so (for example) every `Person` sorts before every `Dog`, which sorts before every `Dream`, and so on. Then you'll have to define an ordering within each type about like you usually would.

I'd warn, however, that this typically involves quite a bit of extra work, and provides very little value in return. I'd say well over 90% of the time I've seen people (try to) do this, it's been a mistake that worked out poorly at best. If at all possible, I'd try to find some other approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be possible to, for instance, compare the data by their binary values, but I'm not sure if I can do that..

Comment: @vtleavs: No, not meaningfully. Just for example, it won't handle floating point values correctly--they have both a negative zero and a positive zero, that should compare equal to each other, but if you look at the bits, they'll be different.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a class similar to `poly_key`, which will accept any type provided that it is:

- copyable or moveable (copyable for this demo)
- equality comparable (if used in unordered map)
- less-than comparable (if used in map)
- hashable (if used in ordered map)
- ostreamable (for this demo)

like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

/// a non-polymorphic container for a polymorphic key type
struct poly_key
{
    /// concept defines the key's capabilities
    struct concept {

        virtual bool equal(const void* other) = 0;
        virtual bool less(const void* other) = 0;
        virtual const void* address() const = 0;
        virtual const std::type_info& type() const = 0;
        virtual std::size_t hash() const = 0;
        virtual std::ostream& emit(std::ostream&) const = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const = 0;
        virtual ~concept() = default;
    };

    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<concept>;

    /// model<> models the concept for any key which supports the required operations
    template<class T>
    struct model : concept {
        model(T&& t) : _t(std::move(t)) {}

        bool equal(const void* other) override {
            return _t == (*reinterpret_cast<const T*>(other));
        }

        bool less(const void* other) override {
            return _t < (*reinterpret_cast<const T*>(other));
        }

        const void* address() const override {
            return std::addressof(_t);
        }
        const std::type_info& type() const override {
            return typeid(_t);
        }

        std::size_t hash() const override {
            return std::hash<T>()(_t);
        }

        std::ostream& emit(std::ostream& os) const override
        {
            return os << _t;
        }

        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const override
        {
            return std::make_unique<model>(*this);
        }


        T _t;
    };

    template<class T>
    poly_key(T t) : _impl(std::make_unique<model<T>>(std::move(t))) {}

    std::size_t hash() const {
        return _impl->hash();
    }

    bool operator==(const poly_key& r) const {
        return _impl->type() == r._impl->type()
        && _impl->equal(r._impl->address());
    }

    bool operator<(const poly_key& r) const {
        auto& lt = _impl->type();
        auto& rt = r._impl->type();

        if (lt.before(rt)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (rt.before(lt)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return _impl->less(r._impl->address());
        }
    }

    poly_key(const poly_key& r)
    : _impl(r._impl->clone())
    {

    }

    poly_key(poly_key&& r)
    : _impl(std::move(r._impl))
    {

    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const poly_key& k)
    {
        return k._impl->emit(os);
    }

    ptr_type _impl;
};

/// make it hashable
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<::poly_key> {
        bool operator()(const ::poly_key& r) const {
            return r.hash();
        }
    };
}

//
// test
//
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<poly_key, std::string> m;

    m.emplace(poly_key(std::string("key 1")), "Hello");
    m.emplace(poly_key(2), "World");

    std::cout << "unordered:\n";
    for (auto& e : m) {
        std::cout << e.first << " : " << e.second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nordered:\n";
    std::map<poly_key, std::string> m2 (m.begin(), m.end());
    for (auto& e : m2) {
        std::cout << e.first << " : " << e.second << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

example output (order may vary depending on toolset):

```
unordered:
2 : World
key 1 : Hello

ordered:
key 1 : Hello
2 : World
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a *name* to your types and use it with your map:

```
#include<map>
#include<cassert>

struct B { static int cnt; };
int B::cnt = 0;

template<typename T>
struct D: B { static const int type; };

template<typename T>
const int D<T>::type = B::cnt++;

std::map<int, int> values;

template<typename T>
void set(int value) { values[D<T>::type] = value; }

template<typename T>
int get() { return values[D<T>::type]; }

struct T1 { };
struct T2 { };

int main() {
    set<T1>(42);
    set<T2>(0);
    assert(get<T1>() == 42);
    assert(get<T2>() == 0);
    set<T2>(3);
    assert(get<T2>() == 3);
}
```